# FireDAC TFDConnection SSL hangs

Tags: delphi, pascal, firedac

I define  a TFDConnection in code myself using this. TablePlus connects fine with these certs, but the firedac connection just hangs the program. Connection without SSL works fine. Is there any way to see why it hangs or get it to connect using SSL too?

```
conn := TFDConnection.Create(nil);
conn.Params.DriverID := 'MySQL';
conn.Params.Add('Server='+serverAddress);
conn.Params.Database := databaseName;
conn.Params.UserName := userName;
conn.Params.Password := passWord;
conn.Params.Add('UseSSL=True');
conn.Params.Add('SSL_key=client-key.pem');
conn.Params.Add('SSL_ca=ca.pem');
conn.Params.Add('SSL_cert=client-cert.pem');
conn.LoginPrompt := False;


try
  conn.Connected := True;
  dbQuery := TFDQuery.Create(nil);
  dbQuery.Connection := conn;
except
  MessageDlg('Viga', mtError, [mbOK],0);
  raise;
end;
```

The code hangs on the line `conn.Connected := True;` when `SSL` is used.

Comment: Why don't you show the exception's message rather than ignoring it and displaying "Viga" instead?

Comment: The except never happens so there is no error here. The entire thing just hangs

Comment: On which line does it hang when you single step through the code? To single step, put a break point on the first line, then single step using F8.

Comment: conn.Connected := True; @TomBrunberg

Comment: Try manually doing it in the IDE and check the Info tab of the FireDAC Connection Editor.

Comment: I have now tried a TFDPhysMySQLDriverLink too. Same result